# How to do unattended install of WebSVN with apt-get?

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get, websvn

Working with Ubuntu 10.10 ...

When installing WebSVN via apt-get with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get -y install websvn
```

It will pop 3 screens asking for configuration details (ie. where your SVN repositories are etc).

Is there a way to pass this information to this command so that the installation can occur unattended?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try adding the --force-yes option?I just read that it's different from the -y option

Comment: The `--force-yes` option only applies to prompts from `apt-get` itself - usually questions about which packages to install etc. My issue is with prompts from the packages that are being installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost all packages in Debian/Ubuntu use [Debconf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debconf_%28software_package%29). You can pre-seed answers into debconf using the command `debconf-set-selections`.  You need another tool `debconf-get-selections` to extract the answers you provided interactively.  `debconf-get-selections` isn't installed by default, and doesn't need to be installed on the system you are installing to, but you will probably need to install it to extract your answers for the pre-seeding.  This is part of the [debconf-utils](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=debconf-utils) package.